# Laravel routes not updating

Tags: php, laravel, routes

am new to laravel and got stuck at my first project. my biggest problem is with routes.php, have created and edited the app/http/routes.php but still shows the default routes on passing the command `php artisan route:list` which is

```
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
```

my routes.php file is

```
<?php

use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
*Display all tasks
*/
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('tasks');
});

/*
*Add a new task
*/
Route::post('/task', function(Request $request) {
    //
});

/*
*Delete a task
*/
Route::delete('/task{id}', function($id) {
    //
});
```

What am I doing wrong because google has not helped me much so far and its just driving me nuts. Thanks in advance.
Also did this
[Cleared routes cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irN33.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You are using 5.3 Version of Laravel.

The new route.php file lies at

```
app/routes/web.php
```

Add your entries there.

And delete your routes.php file which you've created manually.

Comment: Done that, still no changes, plus clearing the cache several times

Comment: here is something interesting maybe it will be of help, i have cloned another project to my local drive, and it works fine when you call route:list in its directory, but in my project still the same issue. the project is quickstart-basic from the laravel site github profile

Comment: Please check if you've disabled OPcache & PageSpeed from your xampp installation.

Comment: actually i had already found out that the default routes file is routes/web.php -> my answer below, so shifting my routing code there worked like charm @moraya.re

Answer (score 0):

So apparently all the default routes are stored in routes folder, and here the web.php and the api.php both have routes configured, so the web.php is where you edit and include all your routes in Laravel 5.3 and @moraya.re thanks because your post gave me the idea to search for the routes location and this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing) explains it more.

Answer (score 0):

Change your delete url from

```
/*
*Delete a task
*/
Route::delete('/task{id}', function($id) {
    //
});
```

to

```
/*
*Delete a task
*/
Route::delete('/task/{id}', function($id) {
  //
});
```

Comment: even though it doesnt answer the primary question?

Comment: When i add above routes, its getting display in my route list.  Please try following command  "php artisan config:cache", "php artisan route:clear", "php artisan cache:clear".